# Mi variable de javascript no sobrepasa el valor de 1

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un código de javascript (está más abajo) donde esta declarada una variable con el valor inicial de 0.

Quiero que al tocar el div, su valor se fije en 1, y al tocar por segunda vez, su valor se fije en 2.

El problema está en que cuando toco el div por primera vez sí suma 1, pero cuando lo hago por segunda vez, no se sigue incrementando.

Este es el código:

```
<div id="taptoread"  
     ontouchstart="if(touch1403171021t < 2){ touch1403171021t++; }" 
     ontouchmove="if(touch1403171021t > 0){ touch1403171021t--; }" 
     ontouchend="if(touch1403171021t == 2){alert('ee')}; 
                 if(touch1403171021t == 1){ 
                     $('#taptoread').css({'opacity':'1'}); 
                     $('.1403171021').slideDown(170);}" 
     style="opacity:0.7;border-radius:7px;padding-
     bottom:7px;background-color:lightyellow;margin:0px 7px 0px 7px;" 
></div>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer tu pregunta en español?

Comment: Hola Kevin. Si te fijas bien, el sitio se llama "StackOverflow en **Español**"; por ende, tus preguntas deben estar en ese idioma.

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo y bueno el sitio me sale en ingles por eso lo he formulado en ingles pero lo cambiare entonces

Comment: Y qué pasa si comentas, por un momento, el evento `ontouchmove`? A lo mejor está compitiendo con el evento `ontouchstart`.

Comment: Pues lo acabo de probar y sigue haciendo lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo lo haría de esta forma creo un objeto asi:

```
var myObj = {
        touch : 0,

        inc : function() {
            this.touch++;
            console.log(this.touch);
        },

        dec : function () {
            if (this.touch > 0) {
                this.touch--;
            }
            console.log(this.touch);

        },

        action : function () {
            console.log(this.touch);
            if (this.touch === 2) {
                alert('ee')
            } else if (this.touch === 1){
                 $('#taptoread').css({'opacity':'1'}); 
                 $('.1403171021').slideDown(170);
            }
        }

}
```

y el div :

```
<div id="taptoread"  
     ontouchstart="myObj.inc();" 
     ontouchmove="myObj.dec();" 
     ontouchend="myObj.action()" 
     style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; opacity:0.7;border-radius:7px;padding-
     bottom:7px;background-color:lightyellow;margin:0px 7px 0px 7px;" 
></div>
```

en la consola del navegador te daras cuenta de que la variable touch si aumenta

Comment: Muchas gracias juan, lo probare aver si funciona, estoy de viaje y estoy desarrollando en el smartphone y claro no tengo consola para ver que pasa

Comment: Pasa lo mismo pues vaya tela es la cosa mas rara que me ha pasado ya que el codigo esta perfecto vamos que lo he revisado varias veces y se queda bloqueado en 1

Comment: en que lo esta programando?

Comment: Eureka ya lo he solucionado el problema estaba en que un div estaba cubriendo este otro cuando le daba la primera vez, lo he solucionado añadiendole position:relative y bueno aun asi el codigo que me has propuesto va estupendo me ha abierto mas posiblidades asique muchas gracias por la ayuda y por enseñarme algo nuevo estaba ya desesperado 3 dias llevava sin poder avanzar

Comment: Ok con gusto para eso es esta comunidad